# JQuery and calling PHP using AJAX using POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a Final Exam Review guide for my Physics Class, but I want to be able to view my (and others') previous scores in a text file log. What I have is a pre-made text file called "scorelog.txt", my javascript file is called "phpjs.js", HTML file called "physics-with-php.hmtl" and my PHP file is called "submitlog.php". My question is:
When I press the 'next' button in my html for the last time, it gives the alert box, but it seems that it isn't sending data to PHP **or** it could be the PHP isn't writing to the text file. I am pretty sure it isn't the latter, as I have checked my PHP time and again.

**Javascript**

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var totalQuestions = $('.questions').size();
        var currentQuestion = 0;
        $questions = $('.questions');
        $submitBtn = $('.subBtn');
        $questions.hide();
        $submitBtn.hide();
        $($questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeIn();
        $('#next').click(function() {
            $($questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeOut(function() {
                currentQuestion = currentQuestion + 1;
                if (currentQuestion == totalQuestions) {
                    var score = 0;
                    score = parseInt($("input:radio[name='1']:checked").val()) + parseInt($("input:radio[name='2']:checked").val()) + parseInt($("input:radio[name='3']:checked").val()) + parseInt($("input:radio[name='4']:checked").val()) + parseInt($("input:radio[name='5']:checked").val());
                    alert("Your score: " + score + " / 5");
                    var fullname = $('$.FullName').val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "submitlog.php",
                        data: {"finalscore: score, name: fullname"},
                        success: function(data) {
                            alert("Your score of " + data + " has been logged");
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    $($questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeIn();
                }
            });

        });

    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cumulative Practice</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery-1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='phpjs.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1>Cumulative Test</h1>
            Full Name: <input type="text" id="FullName" name="Fullname" class="FullName"/>
            <p class="instructions">
                Select the best answer for each question, then press next.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="questions">
            <p>1. Two vertical walls are separated by a distance of 1.5 m, as the
                drawing shows. Wall 1 is smooth, while wall 2 is not smooth. A uniform
                board is propped between them. The coefficient of static friction
                between the board and wall 2 is 0.98. What is the length of the longest
                board that can be propped between the walls?</p>
            <form class="options">
                <input class="option" type="radio" name="1" value=0> 43 meters<br>
                <input class="option" type="radio" name="1" value=1> 67 meters<br>
                <input class="option" type="radio" name="1" value=0> 63.5 meters<br>
                <input class="option" type="radio" name="1" value=0> 57 meters<br>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="questions">
            <p>2.  Two submarines are under water and approaching each
                other head-on. Sub A has a speed of 12 m/s and sub B has a speed
                of 8 m/s. Sub A sends out a 1550-Hz sonar wave that travels at a
                speed of 1522 m/s. What is the frequency detected by sub B?</p>
            <form class="options">
                <input class="option" type="radio" name="2" value=0> 1495 Hz<br>
                <input class="option" type="radio" name="2" value=0> 1625 Hz<br>
                <input class="option" type="radio" name="2" value=1> 1570 Hz<br>
                <input class="option" type="radio" name="2" value=0> 1590 Hz<br>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="questions">
            <p>3. Two converging lenses are separated by 24.00 cm. The focal
                length of each lens is 12.00 cm. An object is placed 36.00 cm to the
                left of the lens that is on the left. Determine the final image distance
                relative to the lens on the right. Hint: Try drawing a ray diagram.</p>
            <form class="options">
                <input class="option" type="radio" name="3" value=0> 12 cm<br>
                <input class="option" type="radio" name="3" value=0> -10 cm<br>
                <input class="option" type="radio" name="3" value=0> 13 cm<br>
                <input class="option" type="radio" name="3" value=0> -24 cm<br>
                <input class="option" type="radio" name="3" value=1> -12 cm<br>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="questions">
            <p>4. A mirror produces an image that is located 34.0 cm behind the
                mirror when the object is located 7.50 cm in front of the mirror. What
                is the focal length of the mirror, and is the mirror concave or convex? </p>
            <form class="options">
                <input class="option" type="radio" name="4" value=0> 9.62 cm; Concave<br>
                <input class="option" type="radio" name="4" value=1> 9.62 cm; Convex<br>
                <input class="option" type="radio" name="4" value=0> 0.104 cm; Concave<br>
                <input class="option" type="radio" name="4" value=0> 8.104 cm; Convex<br>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="questions">
            <p>5. An object is located 14.0 cm in front of a convex mirror, the
                image being 7.00 cm behind the mirror. A second object, twice as tall
                as the first one, is placed in front of the mirror, but at a different location.
                The image of this second object has the same height as the other
                image. How far in front of the mirror is the second object located?</p>
            <form class="options">
                <input class="option" type="radio" name="5" value=0> 21 cm<br>
                <input class="option" type="radio" name="5" value=0> 28 cm<br>
                <input class="option" type="radio" name="5" value=1> 42 cm<br>
                <input class="option" type="radio" name="5" value=0> 7 cm<br>
            </form>
        </div>
        <br>
        <input type="button" id='next' value="Next" />
    </body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$logfile = "scorelog.txt";
$fh = fopen($logfile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$score = $_POST['finalscore'];
$fullname = $_POST['name'];
$stringdata = "$fullname scored $score points\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringdata);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Install firebug. In the console tab you can see, what ajax is sending. Im sure you will find the solution by your own in 5 mins. And your PHP has no output...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `data` parameter looks bad:

```
data: {"finalscore: score, name: fullname"},
```

Should probably be:

```
data: { "finalscore": score, "name": fullname },
```

`data` has to be a key value pair.

Your PHP script probably also isn't very robust, it *should* throw an error if it gets input it doesn't expect. It's a bit more advanced but you want your scripts to behave like that. Validate your input and crashing early will save you a lot of time in the long run :) Then you don't have to say things like *"I think it's fine"*, because you'll *know*.

Comment: meh beat me to it...plus 1

Answer (score 0):

your data parameter should be like below

```
data: {finalscore: score, name: fullname},
```